# How to execute code in a C# service one time per day at the same hour

Tags: c#, service, scheduling

I need to start a C# service running on a server once per day at 3AM. I think that I can do it with a `thread.sleep()` or by comparing `DateTime.Now` with 3AM in code that runs 24/7.

Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

Write a console app or equivalent, and use the Windows Task Scheduler to run it daily.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Scheduled Tasks successfully for backups, but I have a word of caution ...

Scheduled tasks may not be performed if you log out. I'm not sure if this can be overridden, but I have been caught out by tasks not performed because Windows automatically updates, reboots and sits waiting for me to log-in.

Another consideration is that 3AM is a time when many users would normally be logged out.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking...I've try the scheduled task and after the server reboot nothing start... Thank you!

Comment: I must say, I have never had the issue myself. Always worked 100% for me.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that even back in 2009 (Windows Vista/Server 2008 R2 era) there was an option in Windows Task Scheduler to have tasks run whether a user was logged in or not.

Answer (score 2):

> compare the DateTime.Now with 3am

This is a bad solution, even if you sleep for some time between each check, as it wastes system resources unnecessarily (not only in repeatedly checking the time, but also in the memory usage of the program).

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting a file every night, instead of worrying about when it arrives, just get an event fired when it does.

Look at:

`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`

[File System Watcher on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`System.Threading.Timer` might work out for you.

[Documented here](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Threading/types/Timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why not set this up to run as a scheduled task? Have it execute and then exit. Set up Windows to start the process as a scheduled task at 3:00 AM daily.