# Perform a function at a specific time in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a small app to automatically connect my PC to the internet at a certain time and
I am using `rasdial.exe` for it...

```
Private Sub SetIt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SetIt.Click
    Dim windir As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR")
    Shell(windir & "\system32\rasdial.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalNoFocus)
End Sub
```

My question is how to make the shell function run at a specified time or after a certain interval??

Also how to wake up my PC from hibernation using vb and winresume.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a console application to do the work necessary, and then use a Windows Scheduled Task to do the scheduling work for you. My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373306/how-to-execute-code-in-c-service-one-time-per-day-at-the-same-hour/1373321#1373321) shows how to accomplish the scheduling.

Comment: and how to delete the task if the app is closed...
(all the time the app will be running in the background)