# How to schedule a DLL of Web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, dll, exe

I have created one project to generate PDFs through itextsharp. Now I want to schedule dll of this project to run this project daily at 7 AM. Please help me how we can schedule dll.

Comment: Windows Scheduled task?

Comment: How to do this Windows Scheduled task? Please explain a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an exe and create a Scheduled task to run it daily at 7AM.

> search?q=creating+a+scheduled+task

Comment: How to wrap a dll in exe?

Comment: Create a new Console Application and reference the dll. A dll has no entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Task Scheduler or a Windows Service. Both options are explained here: [How to execute code in c# service one time per day at the same hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373306/how-to-execute-code-in-c-sharp-service-one-time-per-day-at-the-same-hour)